# Changing aesthetics in R plotly radar chart

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to change reverse the colors of the following plotly radar chart, as well as removing the -0.2 in the axis labels [image] This plot was produced by the following code:

```
fig <- plot_ly(
      type = 'scatterpolar',
      fill = 'toself'
    )
fig <- fig %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.numeric(threats.mod["Country avg.", ]),
        theta = threat.labs,
        name = 'Country Avg.'
      ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.numeric(threats.mod["Selection", ]),
        theta = threat.labs,
        name = 'Selection'
      ) %>%
      layout(
        polar = list(
          radialaxis = list(
            visible = T,
            range = c(-0.2,1)
          )
        )
      )
    fig
```

Comment: Does it really make sense to make a radar chart that starts at -0.2?

Comment: It's a device to get plotly to produce a similar graphical result to radarplot, which has an empty core. https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/142-basic-radar-chart.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I fixed it:

```
fig <- plot_ly(
      type = 'scatterpolar',
      fill = 'toself',
      marker = list(colorscale="Greys")
    )
    fig <- fig %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.numeric(threats.mod["Country avg.", ]),
        theta = threat.labs,
        name = 'Country Avg.',
        fillcolor=rgb(153, 213, 148, 150, maxColorValue = 255),
        marker=list(color=rgb(153, 213, 148, maxColorValue = 255))
        ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = as.numeric(threats.mod["Selection", ]),
        theta = threat.labs,
        name = 'Selection',
        fillcolor=rgb(252, 141,89, 150, maxColorValue = 255),
        marker=list(color=rgb(252, 141, 89, maxColorValue = 255))
      ) %>%
      layout(
        polar = list(
          radialaxis = list(
            visible = T,
            range = c(-20,100),
            tickmode = "array",
            tickvals = c(0, 50, 100),
            ticktext = c("0%", "50%", "100%"),
            angle= 0,
            tickangle = 0
          )
        )
      )
```